# Failed to add/edit artifact details. A valid qualified name was not set for this artifact

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to create a custom artifact type in WSO2 Governance Registry 4.6.0 to have a custom metadata for my services.

When I try to save the new artifact I have this error:

**A valid qualified name was not set for this artifact**

The system log is showing:

> TID[-1234] [Greg] [2013-11-27 11:26:05,947] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - A valid
>   qualified name was not set for this artifact
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:398)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>   org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.stub.ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.addArtifact(ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.java:3452)
>   org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.clients.ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.addArtifact(ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.java:104)
>   org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.utils.ManageGenericArtifactUtil.addArtifactContent(ManageGenericArtifactUtil.java:60)
>   org.apache.jsp.generic.add_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.generic.add_005fajaxprocessor_jsp:95)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:101)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Does anybody faced this kind of error??

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the configuration of the new artifact might be able to help if after looking at the config

Comment: I've translated the name field and i've got this error. Now i used the label attribute for this translation and it works:
<name label="Nom">Name</name>

Comment: great nice to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Check these

- artifactType
- storagePath

Eg:-

```
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-employee+xml" shortName="employee" singularLabel="Employee" pluralLabel="Employees" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="11">
   <storagePath>/employees/@{overview_name}</storagePath>
   <nameAttribute>overview_name</nameAttribute>
   <ui>
     <list>
       <column name="Name">
          <data type="path" value="overview_name" href="@{storagePath}"/>
       </column>
       <column name="Type">
          <data type="path" value="overview_type" />
       </column>

       <column name="Address">
          <data type="text" value="overview_address"/>
       </column>
       <column name="Sex">
          <data type="text" value="overview_sex"/>
       </column>
     </list>
   </ui>
   <content>
     <table name="Overview">
       <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
          <name>Name</name>
       </field>
        <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
          <name>Type</name>
       </field>
       <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
          <name>Address</name>
       </field>
       <field type="options" readonly="true">
          <name label="Sex">Sex</name>
          <values>
             <value>male</value>
             <value>female</value>
          </values>
       </field>
     </table>
   </content>
</artifactType>
```